# How to set up toolbar to be fixed in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In vuetify I use a toolbar

```
    <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
        <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer.drawer = !drawer.drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
        <v-toolbar-title>{{drawer.title}}</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>
    <router-view v-bind:page="pageData"></router-view>
```

But I want to make it fixed, and not overlap with the vuerouter contents. How can I do that? I tried putting `fixed` but it still overlaps.

Thanks

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of what you're getting?

Comment: fixed it with this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boxqwY

Comment: The codepen code is not loading properly. It must be a mistake with the code @omega

Answer (score 8):

Since version 2.0.0 v-toolbar isn't fixable use v-app-bar https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars

Answer (score 5):

Use css arguments in `style` tags.
Cf.) https://journal.simondepelchin.be/2019/03/04/how-to-make-a-sticky-tabs-bar-with-vuetify/

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar class="fixed-bar">
    <!-- ... -->
  </v-toolbar>
</template>


<style scoped>
.fixed-bar {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  top: 6em;
  z-index: 2;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Add the `app` attribute to the toolbar
2. Put your router outlet content inside a `v-content` element.
3. Finally, make sure the whole shebang is inside a `v-app` element.

Comment: this doesn't make it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use app-bar outside from router-view
Use this example https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/#application

```html
<!-- App.vue -->

<v-app>
  <v-navigation-drawer app>
    <!-- -->
  </v-navigation-drawer>

  <v-app-bar app>
    <!-- -->
  </v-app-bar>

  <!-- Sizes your content based upon application components -->
  <v-content>

    <!-- Provides the application the proper gutter -->
    <v-container fluid>

      <!-- If using vue-router -->
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>

  <v-footer app>
    <!-- -->
  </v-footer>
</v-app>
```