# Vuetify sticky header toolbar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I use `v-toolbar` but when I scroll down it get disappears. Basically I want to a sticky header.

This is my code basically.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar dense>
    <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
   <main>
     <h1 v-for="n in 20" :key="n">{{n}}</h1>
    </main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up toolbar to be fixed in vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217709/how-to-set-up-toolbar-to-be-fixed-in-vuetify)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit: Vuetify version 1.5:**

You just need to add `fixed` to your `v-toolbar` which fixes the position, So:

```
<v-toolbar dense fixed>
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars)

**Version 2.0.0**

[Change from vuetify version 1.5](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0#user-content-upgrade-guide) :

> v-app-bar: Brand new component that was created to better scope the functionality of v-toolbar. All existing scrolling techniques and app functionality from v-toolbar has been moved. New scrolling techniques such as collapsing bar, scroll shrink and more have been added.

`<v-app-bar fixed>` would fix the toolbar. [Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars#api)

Comment: Looks like `fixed` no longer is a prop for `v-toolbar`.

Comment: @JohanBaaij Thank you for pointing that out. I just updated my answer based on version 2 as well

Comment: Does not seem to work correctly inside a dialog. The toolbar becomes full screen at the top when you say fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

```
<v-app id="inspire">
    <div
      class="hide-overflow"
      style="position: relative;"
    >
      <v-toolbar
        color="teal lighten-3"
        dark
        scroll-off-screen
        scroll-target="#scrolling-techniques"
        dense
      >
        <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
      </v-toolbar>

      <main id="scrolling-techniques" class="scroll-y"
            style="max-height: 625px;">
     <h1 v-for="n in 20" :key="n">{{n}}</h1>
    </main>
    </div>
  </v-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who just wants to have a sticky element either above or below,
you might want to try snackbars

```html
 <v-snackbar v-model="snackbar" timeout="-1" top app>
  jojojojojo asdfjasldf 
 </v-snackbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing of the above helps, make use of good old CSS:

```
<script>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner" class="d-flex align-center cursor-pointer">
            <v-toolbar dense>
             ...
            </v-toolbar>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
#outer {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#inner {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 140px;
    left: 1em;
    padding-left: 16px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
</style>
```

Sources:

- https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning?source=post_page
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning